# How can I debug formatting in LibreOffice?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am using LibreOffice Writer 4.0.2.2 to edit a Word document sent to me by a Microsoft user.  It contains certain formatting that I can't figure out how to change (a gray background on some of the text).

I usually use LaTeX for my text documents, and so I'm used to seeing explicit formatting commands, which make it relatively obvious what to change.  But in this case, I don't know where to look; there seem to be a lot of places where background color can be set.

> In general, does LibreOffice have a way to "debug" formatting, to determine what is causing a certain effect, and help figure out how to change it?

I know some word processors used to have a "reveal codes" feature that would show all formatting directives in the document.  As far as I can tell, LibreOffice doesn't have such a feature, but maybe there is something else that can help me.

(If I don't get an answer to this general question, I'll post a more specific one about the particular bit of formatting I'm trying to excise.)

Comment: The most you can get is Ctrl+F10. You'll see the return, space, tab  characters and some special fields (if used). A full reveal-code (with format/font etc info) is not (yet) available for Libre-/OpenOffice.

Comment: Gray background may indicate a field or formula. Another approach: unzip the `.odt` file (or `.docx`, if you didn't convert it yet) and check the resulting XML source files.

Comment: Hahaha, have you ever unzipped a .odt or .docx and looked for content? Well, i guess it is just what was asked for... to reveal codes... :) And it could help find weird converting errors... if you can find your text.